# writing an empty xml element in c# using xmlwriter

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter, writeelementstring

I'm using xmlwriter in order to edit xml files, but I need it to maintain a specific format for  future comparisons with other xml files.

I'm using the following code to write empty elements:

```
w.WriteStartElement("description");
w.WriteEndElement();
```

the result in the xml file is:

`<description />`

which would normally will be ok, but I need It to look like that:

`<description/>`

without the space character after "description".

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML is not text. The rules are different. In general, you cannot use a text comparison to compare XML files. The two examples you gave are identical XML, yet, as you noted, they are different text.

You can begin to approach this by pre-processing the files to be compared to do things like put all attributes in the same order, perhaps one attribute per line; by placing elements into a canonical order, using the same prefix for the same namespace, etc. You then have to tell your text comparison tool to ignore whitespace, etc.

Comment: I know that both forms are valid xml, but unfortunately I'm using the diff program of tortoise_svn, since all my xml files are in a svn repository and that's why I need this kind of (unnecessary for xml) precession.

Comment: So, it makes sense to you to change your source code because of your repository?

Comment: No, of course not. I thought that there will be some kind of setting that I can change that will remove the white-space, but I guess that the only solution is to check in (commit) the file with the extra white-space to the repository, that way I have the same form of empty elements in the repository.

Comment: That, and make a feature request that they permit per-file-type settings to the diff utility. They might even want to permit you to choose the utility to use for each file type, if not on a file-by-file basis.

Comment: I would use Beyond Compare. It has the ability to do contextual logic-based comparisons, and will solve this and many other comparison problems. A developer license is around $30.

Comment: Beyond compare is a powerful comparison tool and my company has a license for it.

Answer (score 2):

Both of these forms are valid XML, and whatever system your using should be able to parse both forms, lest it *not* be an XML parser.

I'm not at my computer right now, but I feel like this would work:

```
Var myModifiedXmlString = w.ToString().Replace(" />", "/>");
```

Comment: I tried your way but there is no change:
`w.WriteStartElement("description");
 w.WriteEndElement();
 w.ToString().Replace(" />", "/>");`

Comment: @eitanx, the Replace method returns the modified XML string, it does not change the XML in-place.

Comment: so I need to use something like writeraw(), in order to change the xml file and that something I can't do, since writeraw() disrupts all the new line charecters in all the siblings of <description/>.

Comment: You would need to use the "myModifiedXmlString" and compare that instead of using the "xml".

Answer (score 2):

Look at [`XmlWriter.WriteRaw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writeraw.aspx), e.g.:

```
w.WriteRaw("<description/>");
```

Comment: I tried using writeraw, but it disrupts all the new line charecters in all the siblings of <description/> and I get a single line with all the sibling elements of <description/> in the father element of <description/>:

<>